# How to generate dropdownList in Yii2 that has several options with one value

Tags: arrays, select, drop-down-menu, yii2

Is it possible to generate dropdownList in Yii2 like this:

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">Value 1.a</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1.b</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2.abc</option>
</select>
```

In this case `a` and `b` are values from depend table with one-to-many relation.

[image: DB tables image]

Comment: your problem  is create a Yii2 dropdownlist  .. or   a dropdownlist  with the same  value..  ?

Comment: you may check this video  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpj7dF2orbI

Answer (score 0):

i can't realize reason of using multiple options with one value. but if you still wants to using this goal, you should know that in yii you can not handle multiple options with one value.
because dropdownlist options in yii are array and in array if you set multiple value for a key, last value are overriden to first ones.
if you wants this goal, you must generate your dropdownlist with native html.